# What's easiest way to get value of a checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, trygetvalue

what is the easiest way to get the value of a checkbox? 
I create my checkboxes dynamically

```
 function buildList() {
    var output;
    output = "<form><fieldset data-role='controlgroup' data-iconpos='right' id='fieldset_item'>";
    if (codeCounter != 0 && codeCounter > 0 && codeCounter != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < codeCounter; i++) {
            output += "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox_" + i
                    + "' id='checkbox_" + i + "'><label for='checkbox_" + i
                    + "'>" + localStorage.getItem(i) + "</label>";
        }
    }

    output += "</fieldset></form>";
    $(output).appendTo("#fieldSet");
    $('#fieldSet').trigger("create");
}
```

So how can i get the value of the each checkbox?

Comment: Quick tip: Use `<label><input /></label>` to remove the need for an ID/for combo.

Comment: `document.getElementById('checkbox_0').value`?

Comment: Duplicate here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery]

Comment: var id = 'checkbox_1'; var checkboxVal = $('label[for="' + id + '"]').html();

Comment: No need to do anything at all. You haven't given the checkboxes a value, so they're all `""` (empty string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having no value in the checkboxes you're generating, kind of made me feel you want the text inside the label tags, in case I was right:

```
var id = 'checkbox_1'; 
var checkboxLabel = $('label[for="' + id + '"]').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').val()
```

Comment: Which will return the value of the first checked checkbox and ignore the rest (or undefined if none are checked).

Comment: It was more of an example showing how to used the checked pseudo selector. Hence, the easiest way to get the value of A checkbox.